# How to cast data in response with Oligo Odata V4 client?

Tags: java, odata

I wrote a code in java to create a Olingo Odata client V4. I am able to send  queries and receive a response and extract each elements. I want to go further and make some calculations with data I receive:

-I would like to know if it is possible in java to map data I received into a class.

-I am wondering if it is possible to cast data into String, Integer, Long, Double in another way I did below:

```
public List<ItemSales> getItemSale(ClientEntitySetIterator<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity> iteratorItemSales)
{
    List<ItemSales> itemSalesList = new ArrayList<ItemSales>();

    while (iteratorItemSales.hasNext()) {
           ClientEntity resultsIterator = iteratorItemSales.next();
           List<ClientProperty> properties = resultsIterator.getProperties();

           ItemSales itemsales = new ItemSales();
           //EdmCast
           for (ClientProperty property : properties) 
           {
               switch( property.getName().toLowerCase())
               {
                    case "id": itemsales.setId(Long.parseLong(property.getValue().toString())); break;
               }
               ClientValue value =property.getValue();

           }
    }

    return itemSalesList;
}
```

Indeed, once I get in my example, I want to get a long value. Nevertheless all elements of the list I got are in "ClientValue" format.